# an error in RS when I try to aggregate a field

Tags: cognos

I haver cognos on windows server connecting to posgres via postgreSQL ODBC.
I created a report in RS. Whenever I try adding a numeric field to the report, i get this error:

RQP-DEF-0177 An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9'.
UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation "prepare".
No query has been executed with that handle

If I change the field's Aggregate Function to 'None', everything works fine.

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Do all measures fail aggregation? What specific data types are there? Are they correctly seen from within Framework Manager as these data types?

I would generate the SQL from the report without the aggregation, edit it to have aggregation, and run it direct against the database to rule out any data overflow similar issue. [You will not be able to generate the SQL with the aggregation in place].

If not that, my next guess would be the driver itself. What version of Cognos? What OS? 32/64 bit for each? What version of postgre?